# Matlab: How can I control the color of a streamtube plot?

Tags: matlab, plot, colors, velocity

I am currently trying to plot 3D streamtubes. I want the tubes to be colored corresponding to their respective velocity (e.g. slow = blue, fast = red).

To be more exact, I have three 3D-matrices containing the velocity in x, y and z direction. The color of the streamtubes should be `sqrt(vx^2+vy^2+vz^2)`. When using `streamtube(x,y,z,vx,vy,vz,sx,sy,sz)` the tubes are colored according to their z-coordinate which is useless because it's a 3D plot anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well this wasn't easy (it ought to be a builtin option), but by modifying the `CData` of each tube (they are each their own graphics object), you can achieve the desired result. Here's an example

```
load wind
[sx,sy,sz] = meshgrid(80,20:10:50,0:5:15);
h=streamtube(x,y,z,u,v,w,sx,sy,sz);
drawnow
view(3)
axis tight
shading interp;
```

This gives this picture:
[image]

but then doing this:

```
vel=sqrt(u.^2+v.^2+w.^2); %// calculate velocities
for i=1:length(h)
    %// Modify the colour data of each tube
    set(h(i),'CData',interp3(x,y,z,vel,get(h(i),'XData')...
        ,get(h(i),'YData'),get(h(i),'ZData'),'spline'))
end
drawnow
view(3)
axis tight
shading interp;
```

gives this result
[image]

NOTES:

1) I don't know if this is fully correct, I don't know how to test it

2) You have to interpolate the velocity data from the points where it's known onto the vertices of the streamtubes

3) I found the `spline` interpolation option to work best, but the other options might work better in other cases

Comment: This is fantastic! +1. Spline interp should be in general the best for this,

Comment: That's what I've been looking for! I did not know, that one could access each streamtube with `h(i)`. Thank you!